# How to insert a new line or lines in sprcific block of lines in php laravel using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to insert some data or lines in a file in a specific place
For example, I have a file in the laravel project called `web.php` which is a route file
and I want to edit it programmatically and insert a new route within a route group.
So what regex I can use to get the specific part of the route file and insert newlines in it.

example:

```php
Route::group(["prefix" => "admin"], function(){
    Route::resource("users", UserController::class);
    // I want to insert new lines or route here
    // if run next time again it should be inserted here
    // I mean at the end of this group's route
});
```

Which regex will be helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `web.php` file, you can add a marker (such as `// auto-routes: admin`) below your route registration inside the admin group. Then you can use regex (or even simple replace) to replace that line with itself and a new route.

For example:

```php
Route::group(["prefix" => "admin"], function() {
    // auto-routes: admin
    Route::resource("users", UserController::class);
});
```

Then, wherever you want to add a route, you do the following:

```php
$marker = '// auto-routes: admin';
$new_route = 'Route::resource("groups", GroupController::class)'; // change this, or make it dynamic

$routes = file_get_contents('routes/web.php');

$routes = str_replace($flag, $flag . PHP_EOL . $new_route, $routes);

file_put_contents('routes/web.php', $routes);
```

But because you asked about a regex, you can also use `// auto-routes: admin` in a regex and then use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Finding the group without such a marker is hard. That’s because regular expressions are not powerful enough to parse programming languages on their own. More specifically, in the Chomsky hierarchy, regular expressions would be described by [Type-3 grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), whereas most programming languages are described by at least [Type-2 grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which are more powerful. That is where this topic borders on [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), which is much more complex than simple regex replaces. However, then you could skip using a marker.

As a note of caution: altering code programmatically—especially with regex—is challenging. It’s very easy to corrupt your routes file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I do have control over ```web.php``` file but what I am doing is creating a sort of CMS so we can not trust our users/developers because they can change the file so I came up with my own regex which will check the first specific line and the ```)};``` at the end. And in between before ```)};``` it will insert the new line.

Comment: Actually, this is not a full CMS but it is kind of a great helper like admin panel generator which will provide an easy to use GUI and after submitting the CRUD form it will generate all the files related to that resource and also update the ```web.php``` and ```api.php``` file, Which will reduce developer's work a lot (approx 90%-95%).  If you will search ```redprint``` on the codecanyon you will get what I am building but my version will be open source.